# Error deploying node app to google cloud server instance

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

Error deploying node app to google cloud server instance.

I get certificate error.

I'm using google cloud and a node js app.
I just want to put my node app onto my server instance I made on google cloud.

**This is the screen shot of the command line error message:**

[image]

**Adam for your question:**

```
c:\source\test\nodejs-getting-started\1-hello-world>gcloud preview app deploy ap
p.yaml --promote --verbosity debug
DEBUG: Running gcloud.preview.app.deploy with Namespace(__calliope_internal_deep
est_parser=ArgumentParser(prog='gcloud.preview.app.deploy', usage=None, descript
ion="*(BETA)* This command is used to deploy both code and configuration to the
App Engine\nserver.  As an input it takes one or more ``DEPLOYABLES'' that shoul
d be\nuploaded.  A ``DEPLOYABLE'' can be a module's .yaml file or a configuratio
n's\n.yaml file.", version=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'
>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=False), account=None, authority_selector=N
one, authorization_token_file=None, bucket=None, cmd_func=<bound method Command.
Run of <googlecloudsdk.calliope.backend.Command object at 0x02CB6C50>>, command_
path=['gcloud', 'preview', 'app', 'deploy'], configuration=None, deployables=['a
pp.yaml'], docker_build=None, document=None, force=False, format=None, h=None, h
elp=None, http_timeout=None, image_url=None, log_http=None, project=None, promot
e='true', quiet=None, repo_info_file=None, server=None, stop_previous_version=No
ne, trace_email=None, trace_log=False, trace_token=None, user_output_enabled=Non
e, verbosity='debug', version=None).
INFO: Refreshing access_token
DEBUG: API endpoint: [https://appengine.googleapis.com/], API version: [v1beta4]

You are about to deploy the following modules:
 - poolcoverprod/default (from [c:\source\test\nodejs-getting-started\1-hello-wo
rld\app.yaml])
     Deployed URL: [https://poolcoverprod.appspot.com]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?
```

Comment: Could be related to Boot2Docker. Could you post the output of the command 'gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --promote --verbosity debug' ? (As text, not as a screenshot)

Comment: @Adam I've added that above. let me know if you need me to do anything else. thanks

Comment: Do you happen to be connecting to the internet through a proxy?